# How to add a document to a Document library in Sharepoint using GraphAPI?

Tags: sharepoint, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a new document using the Microsoft graph api inside a certain document library.

[image]

I would like to add the document inside this document library.

I tried using this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/*****-****-451d-bc8f0642868b326/drive/root:/Signing/Izjava.pdf:/content` but this only adds the document to the drive root and creates a folder called Signing with a file inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **note** that, you missed including **`DRIVE_ID`** in the query that refers to ID of document library.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment by running the same query as below:***

```json
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE_ID}/drive/root:/Signing/Izjava.pdf:/content
```

**Response:**

[image]

As I missed including  **`DRIVE_ID`** in the query, it added the document to the drive root by creating a folder called **Signing** with a file named **`Izjava.pdf`** inside it like below:

[image]

***To add a new document inside a certain document library, you need to include **`DRIVE_ID`** in the query like below:***

```json
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE_ID}/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/root:/{DOC_NAME}:/content
```

**Response:**

[image]

The document named  **`Izjava.pdf`** created and uploaded to document library **Signing** successfully like below:

[image]

To get the  **`DRIVE_ID`** of your document library, you can query like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE_ID}/drives
```

**Response:**

[image]